# Chaining ajax requests with jQuery's deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a web app which must call the server multiple times. So far, I had a long nested callback chain; but I would like to use jQuery's `when`,`then` etc. functionality. However, I can't seem to get stuff running again after using a `then`.

```
$
.when ($.get('pages/run-tool.html'))
.then (function (args)
{
    // This works fine
    alert(args);
    $('#content').replaceWith (args);
    $('#progress-bar').progressbar ({value: 0});
})
.then ($.get('pages/test.html'))
.done (function(args)
{
    // This prints the same as the last call
    alert (args);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess its some scoping issue, as I can see the second `get` call being executed. Using two different `args` variables does not help as the argument passed to the done function is still the first `get` request.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As an update:

With modern jquery (1.8+) you don't need the preliminary *when* because *get* returns a Deferred Promise.

Also, *pipe* is deprecated. Use *then* instead. Just be sure to return the result of the new get which becomes the Promise attached to by subsequent *then*/*done*/*fail* calls.

So:

```
$.get('pages/run-tool.html')
.then (function (args) { // this will run if the above .get succeeds
    // This works fine
    alert(args);
    $('#content').replaceWith (args);
    $('#progress-bar').progressbar ({value: 0});
})
.then (function() { // this will run after the above then-handler (assuming it ran)
    return $.get('pages/test.html'); // the return value creates a new Deferred object
})
.done (function(args) { // this will run after the second .get succeeds (assuming it ran)
    alert (args); 
});
```

Answer (score 12):

All three callbacks (the two with `then` and the one with `done`) are applied to the same request – the original `when` call.  This is because `then` returns the same Deferred object, rather than a new one, so that you can add multiple event handlers.

You need to use [`pipe`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) instead.

```
$
.when ($.get('pages/run-tool.html'))
.then (function (args)
{
    // This works fine
    alert(args);
    $('#content').replaceWith (args);
    $('#progress-bar').progressbar ({value: 0});
})
.pipe (function() { 
    return $.get('pages/test.html'); // the return value creates a new Deferred object
})
.done (function(args)
{
    alert (args);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I'll accept as soon as stackoverflow allows me to :)

Comment: jQuery chaining still looks horrible to me

Comment: @PHearst Note that this method is now deprecated.

Comment: Pipe is, but it doesn't change the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here is an wonderfully simple and highly effective AJAX chaining / queue plugin. It will execute you ajax methods in sequence one after each other.

It works by accepting an array of methods and then executing them in sequence. It wont execute the next method whilst waiting for a response.

> **//--- THIS PART IS YOUR CODE -----------------------**
>
> $(document).ready(function () {
>
> ```
> var AjaxQ = [];
> AjaxQ[0] = function () { AjaxMethod1(); }
> AjaxQ[1] = function () { AjaxMethod2(); }
> AjaxQ[3] = function () { AjaxMethod3(); }
>
> //Execute methods in sequence
> $(document).sc_ExecuteAjaxQ({ fx: AjaxQ });
> ```
>
> });
>
> **//--- THIS PART IS THE AJAX PLUGIN -------------------**
>
> $.fn.sc_ExecuteAjaxQ = function (options) {
>
> ```
> //? Executes a series of AJAX methods in dequence
>
> var options = $.extend({
>
>     fx: [] //function1 () { }, function2 () { }, function3 () { }
>
> }, options);
>
> if (options.fx.length > 0) {
>
>     var i = 0;
>
>     $(this).unbind('ajaxComplete');
>     $(this).ajaxComplete(function () {
>
>         i++;
>         if (i < options.fx.length && (typeof options.fx[i] == "function")) { options.fx[i](); }
>         else { $(this).unbind('ajaxComplete'); }
>
>     });
>
>     //Execute first item in queue
>     if (typeof options.fx[i] == "function") { options.fx[i](); }
>     else { $(this).unbind('ajaxComplete'); }
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

The answer cdr gave, which has the highest vote at the moment, is not right.

When you have functions a, b, c each returns a $.Deferred() object, and chains the functions like the following:

```
a().then(b).then(c)
```

Both b and c will run once the promise returned from a is resolved. Since both then() functions are tied to the promise of a, this works similiar to other Jquery chaining such as:

```
$('#id').html("<div>hello</div>").css({display:"block"})
```

where both html() and css() function are called on the object returned from $('#id');

So to make a, b, c run after the promise returned from the previous function is resolved, you need to do this:

```
a().then(function(){
    b().then(c)
});
```

Here the call of function c is tied to the promise returned from function b.

You can test this using the following code:

```
function a() {
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        promise.resolve();
        console.log("a");
    }, 1000);
    return promise;
}

function b() {
    console.log("running b");
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        promise.resolve();
        console.log("b");
    }, 500);
    return promise;
}

function c() {
    console.log("running c");
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        promise.resolve();
        console.log("c");
    }, 1500);
    return promise;
}

a().then(b).then(c);
a().then(function(){
    b().then(c)
});
```

Change the promise in function b() from resolve() to reject() and you will see the difference.

Comment: cdr answer is right. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0pb0g70y/ done with your code, with some changes for clarity. `c` does not get called till `b` is ended. The second `then` does not apply to `a` promise, but to the promise returned by `b` (if it does return a promise, which is the case in your example, and in cdr response for its second `then`).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var promise1 = function () {
        return new
        $.Deferred(function (def) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("1");
                def.resolve();
            }, 3000);
        }).promise();
    };

    var promise2 = function () {
        return new
        $.Deferred(function (def) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("2");
                def.resolve();
            }, 2000);
        }).promise();
    };

    var promise3 = function () {
        return new
        $.Deferred(function (def) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("3");
                def.resolve();
            }, 1000);
        }).promise();
    };

    var firstCall = function () {
        console.log("firstCall");
        $.when(promise1())
        .then(function () { secondCall(); });
    };

    var secondCall = function () {
        console.log("secondCall")
        $.when(promise2()).then(function () { thirdCall(); });
    };

    var thirdCall = function () {
        console.log("thirdCall")
        $.when(promise3()).then(function () { console.log("done"); });
    };


    $(document).ready(function () {
        firstCall();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would leave this little exercise here for anyone who may find it useful, we build an array of requests and when they are completed, we can fire a callback function:

```
var urls = [{
    url: 'url1',
    data: 'foo'
}, {
    url: 'url2',
    data: 'foo'
}, {
    url: 'url3',
    data: 'foo'
}, {
    url: 'url4',
    data: 'foo'
}];
var requests = [];
var callback = function (result) {
    console.log('done!');
};

var ajaxFunction = function () {
    for (var request, i = -1; request = urls[++i];) {
        requests.push($.ajax({
            url: request.url,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('success', response);
            }
        }));
    }
};

// using $.when.apply() we can execute a function when all the requests 
// in the array have completed
$.when.apply(new ajaxFunction(), requests).done(function (result) {
    callback(result)
});
```

Answer (score -2):

My way is to apply callback function:

```
A(function(){
       B(function(){
            C()})});
```

where A, B can be written as

```
function A(callback)
$.ajax{
    ...
    success: function(result){
        ...
        if (callback) callback();
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't use jQuery's deferred, however, and it is prone to the "pyramid effect" (unbounded nesting causing heavy indentation). I guess this is what the asker tried to avoid.