# Facebook Javascript API , callback function?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, callback

I am using `Facebooks Javascript API` in my `jQuery Mobile Website` in order to import the `albums` and `photos` of a facebook `page`.

Its fairly easy to use the API :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.api('16907099963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

As you see i make a call to the API here : `FB.api('16907099963/albums',checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));` which will give me all the albums of this page. The call is `asynchronous`. I need to find a way to be able to know when the call has finished. But i really cant find any `callback functions` here..

The API can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

The reason i am asking for this , is that i need to add a jquery mobile "loading" widget , before i call the API and make it stop when the albums have rendered. Any idea on this one?

Comment: Mr. @serg could take a look at this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checkForErrorFirst` is the callback function. I think your are also missing a slash before the page ID in `FB.api`. Quick sollution if you can't edit the `checkForErrorFirst` function:

```
loader.show();
FB.api('/16907099963/albums', function(result) {
  loader.hide();
  checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums)(result);
});
```

Comment: the checkForErrorFirst is a function i made , i dont think it works as a callback function. Also in your example, you hide the loader before the checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums) finish so whats the point there? The albums need to be fetched , rendered , the html file dynamically created and THEN hide the loader. Thank you for trying to help though :)

Comment: I think we don't understand each other well. In my code, the part `loader.hide()` is called after facebook returns the corresponding albums. If the rendering takes much time, the `loader.hide()` should be after `checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums)(result)`

Comment: The call to the api is asynchronous. That means that if you run the code you suggest , loader.hide() will run before the call to the api has finished. I need a way that i will be sure that the asynchronous api call has finished.